# Installing okular via apt-get on bionic gives me

Tags: apt, okular, container

On Ubuntu 18:04 Bionic (installed as a Singularity container) I issue

```
apt-get install okular
```

and I get the message "*E: Unable to locate package okular*".

Why? Is okular not in the apt repositories any more? How do I install it then?

Comment: Do you have the universe repository enabled?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: @DKBose Nothing changed from the default

Comment: @pLumo When I issue `add-apt-repository universe` it says `add-apt-repository: not found`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix would be to use the following command to add the "universe" repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Or, if this returns an error, try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

If none of these work, then inside the terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

and repeat the first command.

Then finally update by typing:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then try installing again by:

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

Hopefully this works out.

Comment: multiverse is not needed for okular.

Comment: hen I issue `add-apt-repository universe` the command line returns `add-apt-repository: not found`.

Comment: @halloleo kindly try `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"` and post the output here if it fails again.