# Installing okular on a barebone ubuntu container where there is no add-apt-repository command

Tags: 18.04, apt, add-apt-repository

I have Ubuntu 18:04 Bionic installed in a Singularity container.(*)

Via the Singularity definition file I try to add the Okular PDF viewer with the command line

```
apt-get install -y okular
```

However I get the message "*E: Unable to locate package okular*" (no other message: No 404 for URL or similar).

From answers to [Installing okular via apt-get on bionic gives me - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229033/installing-okular-via-apt-get-on-bionic-gives-me) I took the advice to add the `universe` repo, but `apt-add-repository` does not seem to be part of the minimal bionic image (I get the message "add-apt-repository: not found").

How can I install okular on this ubuntu image?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this problem by installing the `software-properties-common` package. Then `apt-add-repository` is available. So the whole procedure to install okular is:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository universe
apt-get update
apt-get install -y okular
```

(Thanks [David Trudgian](https://github.com/dctrud) for this tip!)